# Animation with KineticJS in HTML5: Uncaught typeError: object is not a function

Tags: html, kineticjs

Iam coding a HTML5 game, I did exactly as tutorial but I've got an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function". Anyone can help me?

```
  var amplitude = 150;
  var period = 2000;
  animation = new Kinetic.Animation({
       // ERROR APPEARS HERE
      func: function (frame)
      {
      hook.setY(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period));
      hook.setX(fisherGroup.getX());
      },
      node: shapesLayer
    });
  fisherGroup.on("mousedown", function(){
    animation.start();
  });
```

I created: `hook = new Kinetic.Image()` and `fisherGroup = new Kinetic.Group()` above this paragraph.

Comment: Is func: necessary prior to function? Why does that strike me as incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not positive without knowing more about the parameters of your set-up, I would guess that there may be a conflict with your variable name. Try changing the third line to:

```
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation({
```

Then on fisherGroup mousedown, call `anim.start();`

If you're using a framework that extends prototype and uses animation, that may cause an issue. Also, if you have animation set as a global (not declared with var), that may be an issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly as the tutorial, change it to:

```
 var animation = new Kinetic.Animation({function (frame) {
       hook.setY(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period));
       hook.setX(fisherGroup.getX());
    },
    shapesLayer
});
```